# Google Cloud SQL row size limit

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I was wondering what the row size limit in Google Cloud SQL was? For MySQL databases the limit is 65 Kb and I was wondering if that is the case for Google Cloud SQL as well.
Link to MySQL row size limit page:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-count-limit.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud SQL supports MySQL 5.5 and 5.6. The same MySQL row size limit applies.