# Change Google Cloud SQL row size limit

Tags: google-cloud-sql

The Google Cloud SQL row size limit is apparently somewhere around [65 bytes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/column-count-limit.html). How can we increase this limit? I can't find the flag in the list of customizable flags:

> character_set_server, default_time_zone, event_scheduler,
>   ft_max_word_len, ft_min_word_len, ft_query_expansion_limit,
>   general_log, group_concat_max_len, innodb_file_per_table,
>   innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit, innodb_ft_max_token_size,
>   innodb_ft_min_token_size, innodb_ft_server_stopword_table,
>   innodb_lock_wait_timeout, interactive_timeout, local_infile,
>   log_bin_trust_function_creators, log_output,
>   log_queries_not_using_indexes, long_query_time,
>   lower_case_table_names, max_allowed_packet, max_heap_table_size,
>   max_prepared_stmt_count, optimizer_search_depth, read_only,
>   skip_show_database, slow_query_log, sql_mode, tmp_table_size,
>   wait_timeout

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Cloud SQL row size limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769689/google-cloud-sql-row-size-limit)

Comment: Yes it's a dup. The limit can't be increased. Also it's 65,535 bytes, not 65.

Comment: I don't think it's a dup, I was asking if it can be *changed*, not what the limit is.